# Can a USB 1.0 low speed device negotiate for 500 mA of current from a host?

Tags: usb, usb-device

It is my understanding that a USB 2.0 High Speed device can never negotiate for more than 500 mA of current, even if it is connected to USB 3.0 Super Speed host. That is because the Configuration descriptor field bMaxPower of USB 2.0 is in 2 mA units.

However, can a low speed device negotiate for 500 mA of current from a 2.0 host? Since low speed devices have a maximum current limit of 100 mA.

Comment: is it for your own use (DIY/hobby project) or are you going to sell it to people? if you are making something just for yourself, you can cheat, and use the current without negotiating, in most cases

Comment: @user253751 yes it's for a commercial product

Comment: Under USB2, devices do not negotiate. They only inform the host about their needs.